# How to sort ordered lists based on numbers from smallest to biggest in java?

Tags: java

I am trying to sort an ordered list with objects, but I am not sure how to do it.  I am putting in objects with a population(integer) associated with it. How would I make a method to sort the list so that the object with the lowest population would be first, and the object with the highest population would be last.

Comment: Needs code.  Most folks use `Arrays.sort()` or `Collections.sort()`

Comment: Also, what version of Java are you using?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5932720/how-to-sort-an-attribute-of-an-object-using-collections Found by Google "java sort by attribute"

Comment: E.g. `cities.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(City::getPopulation))`

Answer (score 1):

*"For any class to support natural ordering, it should implement the Comparable interface and override it’s compareTo() method. It must return a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as this object is less than, equal to, or greater than the specified object."*

```
public class YourObject implements Comparable<YourObject> {

  int population;

  YourObject(int pop) {
    population = pop;
  }

  @Override
  public int compareTo(YourObject other) 
  {
      return this.population - other.population;
  }
}
```

then you can use `Collections.sort(list)` on your list

Comment: Don't use subtraction to sort by `int` values. Use [`Integer.compare(int x, int y)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#compare-int-int-).